# StringToDate and non-static variable

Tags: java, string

For some reason in the line `v = new Versenyzok();` it says "Surround with...", i thought I need a method for `Versenyzok`, and I made it, but the issue is still.
The other issue is in the line `v = new Versenyzok(adatok[0],adatok[1],adatok[2],adatok[3]);`. Incompatible types:string cannot be converted to Date. But I cannot find the source where I wanna make a string to date format.

```
package vizsgamintaa;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class VizsgaMintaA {

    static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");
   static Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<Versenyzok> versenyzok = new ArrayList<>();
        Feltolt(versenyzok);
    }
    private static void Feltolt(ArrayList<Versenyzok> versenyzok) throws ParseException{
    Versenyzok v;
    File f = new File("versenyzok.txt");
    try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(f, "iso-8859-2");
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                String sor = scan.nextLine();
                String[] adatok = sor.split(";");
                if (adatok.length == 4) {
                   v = new Versenyzok();
                   v.nev = adatok[0];
                    v.szuletes = df.parse(adatok[1]);
                     v.csapat = adatok[2];
                    if (adatok[3].length()<1) {
                        v.vbcim = 0;
                    } else {
                        v.vbcim = Integer.parseInt(adatok[3]);

                    }
                } else {
                     v = new Versenyzok(adatok[0],adatok[1],adatok[2],adatok[3]);
                }
                versenyzok.add(v);

            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Nincs meg a fájl.");
        }

}

   class Versenyzok {

       String nev,csapat;
       Date szuletes;
       int vbcim;
       SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd");

        @Override
   public String toString(){
   return "Versenyzo:" +nev + "Született:" + df.format(szuletes)+"Csapata:"+ csapat + "Vb címek:" + vbcim; 
   }
   public Versenyzok(String nev, Date szuletes, String csapat, int vbcim) {
       this.nev = nev;
       this.szuletes = szuletes;
       this.csapat = csapat;
       this.vbcim = vbcim;

   }
   public Versenyzok(){}
   }
}
```

Comment: [Java string to date conversion](//stackoverflow.com/q/4216745)

Comment: You have `public Versenyzok(){}`, then `}` on the next line.

Comment: I know, I made the same code before, with the same way, and that works, this isn't.

Answer (score 0):

In `public Versenyzok(String nev, Date szuletes, String csapat, int vbcim) {` you are taking in parameter 2 as a date. But in the `else` loop you are putting `adatok[1]` into parameter 2, and here it is still a `string`, hence you need to parse it first.

Comment: Yes, but the `String nev` index is 0, so the `Date szuletes` index is 0. Am I wrong?

Comment: What is the sample string (before splitting) that’s throwing you this error?

Comment: I think the problem comes from the method issue.

Comment: `Sebastian Vettel;1987.07.03.;Ferrari;4` this is a sample from the text file which is used.

Comment: So it happens when adatok.length is less than 4, so it’s going to throw both errors, 1. Cause the `adatok[1]` is being put into an`Date` type object when it is actually a string. 2. As `adatok` doesn’t have 4 elements, trying to access `adatok[3]` would likely to throw an error.

Comment: What could I possibly do with the 2nd error? I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to type 
`v = new Versenyzo (adatok[0],df.parse(adatok[1]),adatok[2],Integer.parseInt(adatok[3]));`

the `df.parse` and `Integer.parseInt`